# Restsharp json to Datagridview

Tags: c#, json

ok I have trying to get this to work and I just can not get it at all.
Json data i am getting fine the part is when I go and when I go to add it to the datagridview I get just the headers and nothing else. Need some help here.

Form1

```
var client = new RestClient(p.WebCloseout);
//client.Timeout = -1;

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "Value");
var thisJsonStr = "{\"Credentials\": { \"ApiKey\": \"string\",\"MerchantID\": \"string\",\"StoreID\":\"string\",\"Username\": \"string\",\"Password\": \"string\"},\"ReportID\": [\"34\"]";

request.AddParameter("application/json", thisJsonStr, ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

var json = (response.Content);
var deseiralizeObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Closeout>(json);

foreach (var closeout in deseiralizeObject.Reports)
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ($"{closeout.CloseoutID}, {closeout.Desc}, {closeout.Start},{closeout.End}");
```

and my class

```
   public class ReportItem
    {
       public string CloseoutID { get; set; }
        public string Desc { get; set; }
        public string Start { get; set; }
        public string End { get; set; }

    }
```

I changed it to this and get the red squiggly lines under the (deseiralizeObject.Reports); area.

```
request.AddParameter("application/json", thisJsonStr, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            
            var json = (response.Content);

             var deseiralizeObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Closeout>(json);
            
             var bindingList = new BindingList<ReportItem>(deseiralizeObject.Reports);
             var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);
             dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
```

Comment: You don't set a grid's DataSource in a loop, you set it once to a collection of objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your `DataGridView` to a `BindingList<T>` and bind your grid to a `BindingSource`

```
var bindingList = new BindingList<ReportItem>(deseiralizeObject.Reports);
var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);
dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
```

Comment: I made the changes but have an issue with it. I edited my post with the info